# Serilog logger for each plugin DLL in One Application

Tags: serilog

My use-case is multiple unrelated DLLs running as plugins in AutoCAD. Each one has the static global Serilog Logger as described at https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers#in-all-apps. They are all configured to write to [Rolling Files](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile).

I have now realised this has created an odd race-condition where the actual logger could be any one, and only one, of the Loggers declared in each plugin DLL (probably depending on which one declared it last).

#### How do I have a separate Rolling File Logger for each plugin?

Is the best practise for this use-case to use a separate `internal static ILogger` for each plugin and write to that static logger?

Comment: The logger-per-plugin approach sounds like the way to go, yes.

Comment: Mate, that's the answer. hint, hint.

Comment: Didn't want to shut down the discussion in case there were better suggestions floating around out there :-)

Comment: No worries. I'll upvote those & accept a better one if it comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logger-per-plugin approach sounds like the way to go, yes.